# Загрузка изображения на сервер через пост запрос

Tags: c#, uwp

Как можно реализовать отправку изображения на сервер + какую нибудь переменную например id который я введу в TextBox(для сортировки на сервере)?

Answer (score 0):

[Эта ссылка ведет в гитхаб-репозиторий MS c примерами](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient)